# Converting a JSON Date to milliseconds

Tags: json, milliseconds

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#symbolchecker").submit(function (event) {
        var symbol = $("#ticker").val();
        if (symbol == "GDP") {
            $.getJSON('http://www.quandl.com/api/v1/datasets/FRED/' + symbol + '.json?')
                .done(function (quandl) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < quandl.data.length; i++) {
                        var numdates = quandl.data[i][0]
                        $('#GDP').append('<li>' + numdates + '</li>');
                    }
                })
        }
        event.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The code above returns values like this : `2013-10-01`

How do I take those values, and convert them into milliseconds and then take those millisecond values and place them in an array?

Comment: That's a date. Do you want milliseconds since Jan 1 1970 or something?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: Yes that is what I am trying to do

Comment: @MarcB posted the answer.